# encode quotes for xss prevention are not displayed in HTML

Tags: character-encoding, xss, quotes, double-quotes, web-inspector

I am scripting an element as `<span>&quot;carbon</span>` in HTML(encoded the quotes) . However, when i inspect the HTMl in chrome/FF, it looks like `<span>"carbon</span>` (even tried by edit as HTMl option too). How can i prove that the double quotes `"` are encoded. Please guide me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Quotes in that location don't need to be escaped, they have no ambiguous meaning there.
2. Use the "View Source" feature to look at the raw source code; the *Element Inspector* gives you a view of the live DOM, which may be completely different than the raw source code you initially sent to the browser.

Comment: Thanks @ deceze, It helped me. However, if i am rendering that HTML element dynamically with same `<span>&quot;carbon</span>`, then how can we cross check regarding the encoded value ? The raw source code will not display these things.

Comment: Then it doesn't really exist as source code as such anyway. Once it's converted to a DOM node, there's no latent source code representation of it left. If it looks okay as DOM content, that's as far as you need to worry about it.